# Insert Data in two table with Primary key

Tags: c#

this my BottomSave i have two table Employee and Contract with primary key of Enumber.

from adding data in to table employee is working

but in adding data into table contract but is not adding

because of my primary key. is there something wrong in my inserting to contract?

```
                MySQL connect = new MySQL();
                connect.Connection_Today();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = MySQL.con;

                // Adding data to table Employee from database

                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Employee(Enumber,Inumber,Pnumber,Fname,Mname,Sname,Age,Bdate,Gender,Mstatus,Nationality,Eaddress,Cnumber,Picture) Values (@Enumber,@Inumber,@Pnumber,@Fname,@Mname,@Sname,@Age,@Bdate,@Gender,@Mstatus,@Nationality,@Eaddress,@Cnumber,@Picture)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enumber", txtEnumber.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Inumber", txtInumber.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pnumber", txtPassport.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", txtPassport.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mname", txtMname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sname", txtSname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtAge.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bdate", DtpBdate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cbGender.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mstatus", cbMstatus.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", txtNationality.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Eaddress", txtEAddress.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cnumber", txtCnumber.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", ImageToBase64(PbImage.Image,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



                // Adding data to table Contract from database
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Contract(Enumber,Position,Salary,CDuration,Scontract,Econtract) Values(@Enumber,@Position,@Salary,@CDuration,@Scontract,@Econtract)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enumber", txtEnumber.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", txtPosition.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", txtSalary.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CDuration", txtCDuration.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Scontract", dtpStart.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Econtract", dtpEnd.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Disconnect();
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message?

Comment: yes the variable name @Enumber has alread beed declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. must declare the scalar variable what its mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your parameter with [`SqlParameterCollection.Clear` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear.aspx) before putting them in your second query because your command *already* have those parameter names which is added in the first command.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Contract(Enumber,Position,Salary,CDuration,Scontract,Econtract) Values(@Enumber,@Position,@Salary,@CDuration,@Scontract,@Econtract)";
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
...
```

Also use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    // Set your CommandText property of your command with parameters.
    // Add your parameters values.
    // Open your connection
    // Execute your query
    // Set your second command to your CommandText property
    // Clear your parameters.
    // Add new parameter values.
    // Execute your second query.
}
```

By the way, don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use [`Add` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx) overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

Comment: @JomarlynTamargo Glad to help.

Comment: i make class to create my global connection string.public static SqlConnection con = null;
     
        public void Connection_Today()
                 {
                 con = new SqlConnection("constring");
                 con.Open();
                 }
        public void Disconnect()
        {
            con.Close();

        }

Comment: how to use this using statement in my class? by the way i will try to edit my code using that add method..

Comment: @JomarlynTamargo You _don't_ need those `Connection_Today` and `Disconnect` methods. Just use them in your code as a variables. [Connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is quite good about handling them. I put an example in my answer.

Comment: i just confuse this line "using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand()"

Comment: @JomarlynTamargo An `SqlCommand` object should be disposed like a connection as well. `CreateCommand` method just creates an `SqlCommand` which is connected with `con` connection.